# Broken Div - Too much margin/padding etc

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm currently following a UDemy course where the instructor is teaching us Full Stack Development from scratch. Problem is, he made a lot of mistakes that I needed to improvise on like adding `<span>` next to sign in, instead of his idea of a `<p>` and my screenshots of the BBC Logo and Sign In button needed it's height modified in order for them to fit properly in that small nav bar.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wadson's BBC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />   
</head>

<style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #topbar {
        background-color: #7A0000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .fixedwidth {
        width: 1050px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    #logodiv {
        padding-top: 15px;
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid #990000;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    #signindiv {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        border-right: 1px solid #990000;
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 45px;
        float: left;
    }

    #signindiv img {
        position: relative;
        top: 15px;
        left: 15px; 
    }

    #signintext {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25px;
    }

    #topmenudiv {
        float: left;
    }

    #topmenudiv ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;

    }

    #topmenudiv li {
        list-style: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        border-right: 1px solid #990000;
        padding: 15px 20px 0px 20px

    }


</style>
<body>
    <div id="container">
            <div id="topbar">
                <div class="fixedwidth">
                    <div id="logodiv">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" height="25px" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="signindiv">
                        <img class="signinhead" src="images/signin.png" height="20px"/><span id="signintext">Sign In</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="topmenudiv">
                        <ul>
                            <li>News</li>
                            <li></li>
                            <li></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div> <!-- /#container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions for an aspiring programmer? How can I think much differently so that I can spot errors while his is talking instead of copying his stuff verbatim? I understand HTML very well, I'm getting stuck on position, margin and padding.

Comment: `How can I think differently so that I can spot errors while he is talking instead of copying his stuff verbatim?` Really the only correct answer to this is for you to practice CSS, do CSS specific courses, read styling blogs watch videos etc. Soon you'll recognize errors instinctively and be able to rely less on instructors.

Comment: @knitevision lol... it really is broken... :'(

Comment: @zer00ne not at all brother, I would really love to learn how to properly find my answers. Where experience lies right now is I'm now searching for the right things because of what my personal understanding of what I am trying to do sucks. also explaining what I need sucks, as you can read above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few things wrong with the code here, I'm not going to go too deep into structure or how using a CSS framework is a great option for beginners(I highly recommend bootstrap and following a tutorial to understand how they use each component as well following a up to date CSS tutorial).

A few quick pointers to fix the problems your border was going past the `#topbar` because the list items were being stacked vertically instead of horizontally. This was fixed by adding float: right; to the `#topmenudiv li`. You need to offset the padding you have on your list item elements by setting a height - the padding in this case `30px`.

Check the updated version below and always try to include a codepen or jsfiddle with your answer whenever possible.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLEENL

Comment: This response fixed about 90% of the issues, thank you, Problem is floating right will make the menu backgrounds so I changed it to `float: left`, also the border on the far left image is not the equal height as everything else, added a height to that as well, but it goes down, and not up. CodePen as requested here: http://codepen.io/iEngineer/pen/xGyQxv

Comment: @iEngineer what is the other 10%, I'll try to help with that as well

Comment: I'm trying a couple things right now to get the `border-right:` to have the 1px line span fully down instead of 50% like it is in that pen. trying to force myself to inspect element try everything before begging for fixed code instead of advice on how to fix it

Comment: @iEngineer here is an updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waYRgZ the addition of #logodiv img and removal of margin and padding on #logodiv did the trick since the border is affected by the margin/padding.

Comment: I understood fully what's going on here; thanks for the margin/padding advice, I am now aware that borders are affected by them

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question:

> Any suggestions for an aspiring programmer? How can I think much differently so that I can spot errors while his is talking instead of copying his stuff verbatim? I understand HTML very well, I'm getting stuck on position, margin and padding.

Use the [CSS property `outline`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/) When you apply it to a class, tag, or id of an element(s), it looks like the [CSS property `border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border). The difference between `border` and `outline` is that `outline` will not affect the area surrounding the element(s) which mikes it perfect for seeing your divs and their actual position.

Place this css under your body rule (ie `body {...}`) in the `<style>` block:

### **CSS**

```
/* body * { outline: 1px solid blue; } */ /* Uncomment to see all elements */
.green { outline: 2px dashed green } /* Highlight in green */
.black { outline: 3px dotted #000; } /* Highlight in black */
.yellow { outline: 4px double #fc0; } /* Highlight in yellow */
```

In order to handle padding and margins easier put the following at the top of your CSS:

### **CSS**

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
```

This will unify all of the elements under one box-sizing rule. An element's dimensions, padding, and border are included to the element's content. Normally by default (`content-box`), only width and height are considered. See this for more on [box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/)

Comment: np, when you get a handle on those concepts, try flexbox  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/